# Replacing a duplicate value in an array with a set value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to build an array that will replace duplicate values will a set value. I'm not sure how to go about doing it though.

```
        var enemy1 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[0].enemyId();
        var enemy2 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[1].enemyId();
        var enemy3 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[2].enemyId();
        var array = [enemy1, enemy2, enemy3];
console.log(array);
array.forEach(function(kValue)) {
// do something
}
```

With this the array will kick out my designated values. ec [410, 411, 412]

In the event that there is a duplicate; [410, 410, 412]

I want to change the duplicate to be a value of 1000.

So that [410, 410, 412]

now equals [410, 1000, 412]

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I'd consider using a javascript map. Each time you encounter an element, you check if it's in the map. If so, spit-out the designated number, 1000. If it's not in the map, insert it then spit-out the freshly inserted one. The `.has` and `.set` methods seem useful... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @Andreas I've tried comparing the values against each other and swapping out the value of the position but i keep getting a typeerror everytime i try that.

Comment: @enhzflep I will reconstruct the array as a map and try that out. Thank you.

Comment: _" i keep getting a typeerror everytime i try that"_ - Please add your attempt ([mcve] -> preferable as snippet (`<>`))

Comment: @Andreas I've actually just solved it by reconstructing into a Map method.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Set` and map a different value for seen values.

```js
const 
    data = [410, 410, 412],
    result = data.map((s => v => s.has(v)
        ? 1000
        : (s.add(v), v)
    )(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

By reconstructing to a Map method I was able to compare variables to themselves a reset the map keys and values to their appropriate values.

```
var enemy1 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[0].enemyId();
        var enemy2 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[1].enemyId();
        var enemy3 = 400 + $gameTroop.members()[2].enemyId();
        let myMap = new Map();
        
        myMap.set(0, enemy1);
        
        if(enemy2 == enemy1) {
            myMap.set(1, 1000);
        } else {
            myMap.set(1, enemy2);
        }
        
        if(enemy3 == enemy2 || enemy3 == enemy1) {
            myMap.set(2, 1000);
        } else {
            myMap.set(2, enemy3);
        }
```

Thank you @enhzflep for the suggestion.